# Get video URL for third party player using vimeo API

Tags: video, video-streaming, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm going to use third-party player, because I don't want to have html player inside of my android and iOS application. As far as I understand vimeo offers nothing for mobile developers. I found that you are able to provide URL for third-party player. Right now, I bought pro subscription. 
But as for now I'm able to receive link only via UI in a certain tab. Is there a programmatical way to do that? To retrieve list of video's and construct a URL for my 3rd party video player?

Comment: Sorry, I found already the answer, I was requesting wrong video, url is availible only for video I upload, not thirdparty, I hope it will save some time  for somebody

Comment: I recommend posting this as an answer so people can easily find it!

Comment: Post the answer!